Declaring a page object in the test class is throwing below error - Appium
I am getting an error when declaring a page object in the test class, as shown in the code below. When I declare the page object in the test method, it works perfectly, which I think is not right.
package test;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import screens.SmlHomeScreen;

public class LoginTest extends BaseTest {
    SmlHomeScreen smlHomeScreen = new SmlHomeScreen();

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Should login to App successfully")
    public void loginTest() throws InterruptedException {
        loginScreen.signIn(configProperty.getUsername(), configProperty.getPassword());
        Assert.assertTrue(smlHomeScreen.getSmlScreenContent().isDisplayed());
    }
}

I am getting this error:
An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: 'POST /element' cannot be proxied to UiAutomator2 server because the instrumentation process is not running (probably crashed). Check the server log and/or the logcat output for more details.

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: 'POST /element' cannot be proxied to UiAutomator2 server because the instrumentation process is not running (probably crashed). Check the server log and/or the logcat output for more details
Build info: version: '4.25.0', revision: '8a8aea2337'
System info: os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'aarch64', os.version: '14.6', java.version: '23'

But if I declare it in the test method like below, it worked perfectly
package test;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.DisplayName;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import screens.SmlHomeScreen;


public class LoginTest extends BaseTest {


    @Test
    @DisplayName("Should login into App successfully")
    public void loginTest() throws InterruptedException {
        loginScreen.signIn(configProperty.getUsername(), configProperty.getPassword());

        SmlHomeScreen smlHomeScreen = new SmlHomeScreen();
        Assert.assertTrue(smlHomeScreen.getSmlScreenContent().isDisplayed());
    }
}

I also tried to declare all the pages in my BaseTest as below:
package test;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeAll;
import org.testng.annotations.*;
import screens.HomeScreen;
import screens.LoginScreen;
import screens.SmlHomeScreen;
import utils.ConfigProperty;
import utils.Driver;


public class BaseTest extends Driver {

    protected LoginScreen loginScreen;
    protected ConfigProperty configProperty
    protected HomeScreen homeScreen;
    protected SmlHomeScreen smlHomeScreen;


    @BeforeMethod
    public void preTest() {
        LoginScreen = new LoginScreen()
        homeScreen = new HomeScreen()
        smlHomeScreen = new SmlHomeScreen()
        configProperty = new ConfigurProperty().
    }

I am getting the same error as before. This is a webdriver exception, and I am finding it difficult to fix this. Please help
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: 'POST /element' cannot be proxied to UiAutomator2 server because the instrumentation process is not running (probably crashed). Check the server log and/or the logcat output for more details
Build info: version: '4.25.0', revision: '8a8aea2337'
System info: os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'aarch64', os.version: '14.6', java.version: '23'
Driver info: io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver
Command: [084af3d7-627c-40e7-af94-c26e0b032d37, findElement {using=-android uiautomator, value=new UiSelector().text("Login").instance(1)}]

